# Getting the pages that the user is administrator

Tags: php, facebook, access-token

I'm looking for a way to list all pages where a given user is an administrator. Is this possible? If so, where should I be looking?

Comment: You'll need to provide a whole lot more information than that :-/ Got any sample code?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are looking to accomplish. If you want to prompt the user to add your app to a page the are an admin of, you can do it through the javascript SDK. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/)

Otherwise, you need to use FQL to query for the information. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_admin/)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the `manage_pages` permission from your user in order to gain access to this information.

Using [Facebooks FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) and the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) you can make a query to the `page_admin` table using the `uid` index to reference your user.

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/fql?q=SELECT page_id, type from page_admin WHERE uid=me()`

## An alternative :

**The `/me/accounts` Graph API endpoint**
In the Graph API's documentation under the [user endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) there is details about the `accounts` connection :

> The Facebook apps and pages owned by the current user.

You also need the `manage_pages` permission from your user here.

Here is a sample output from a call to that endpoint :

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=ABC`

```
...
    {
      "name": "Unicorn Ville", 
      "access_token": "XXX", 
      "category": "Application", 
      "id": "123"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "StackOverflow'em Poker", 
      "access_token": "YYY", 
      "category": "Application", 
      "id": "456"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "The Official Bausley Page", 
      "access_token": "zzz", 
      "category": "Non-profit organization", 
      "id": "789"
    }, 
...
```

Note that `/me/accounts` returns "*apps and pages* owned by the current user";  As such the results you will get will have to be filtered, *removing* all the application entries or alternatively *extracting* only the non "application" values of the category parameter.